# Term name of Step By Step Form

Tags: forms, design-patterns, steps

I'm planing to contribute Web Components as open source. what is the interface term name for Step by Step Form.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a **wizard**, or 'step through', or 'multi-step process'.

From the book [designing interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/) (the book is a little dated, but has a decent collection of interface patterns).

The top portion which shows what step you're on is called a **progress indicator**, or **[progress tracker](http://babich.biz/progress-trackers-in-ux-design/)**
Here's another example:

[image]

Comment: Just added another variation on the name.